# How to secure the Docker hub repository accounts used in the CI/CD pipeline or Automation?

Tags: docker-registry, dockerhub

could anyone share some guidelines around this problem?
As the Docker hub repository is accessible through the internet outside the company , even for private repositories ,an employee leaving the organization can access the images (read/write) provided if he knows the user accounts used in the automation scripts. Assume this employee is a DevOps or a Developer it is too easy to record the username/passwords before he leaves the company. There is a concept of Access Token but then these are still tied to the user-account. Two factor authentication can be enabled for human based login but not for automation jobs (e.g Jenkins/scripts) .

Comment: If you have Docker Hub for teams, your CI/CD should use tokens. Otherwise, I would recommend using a dedicated container registry, such as goharbor.io or container-registry.com

Comment: yes we do use Access Tokens, but these does not have an expiry (token does not support it)  , they are valid as long as we donot change them ..much like password.